# Calling Perl from R using system _a lot_

Tags: r, perl

I have some arcane perl code that computes a distance between two strings. 
I have R code that creates and aligns strings etc. I need to call the Perl code from R tens of thousands of times. I use `system()`.

It looks like every time I call `system('perl ...')` from R, R opens a new shell. I can't figure out how to make R simply send all commands to the same shell or close the shell immediately after opening it and running the `system` call. Eventually, I get a `too many open files` message and everything falls apart.

This is a simple example with a theoretical Hello World script:

```
for (i in seq_along(1:10000)){
  system('perl hello.pl')
}
```

- showConnections(all=T) doesn't show an extra connection open after running `system(perl...)` once.
- system2 doesn't work at all (though I'm not sure it would help).

I'm on macos v10.13.2, R v3.5.2, Rstudio v1.1.456.

How do I get R to not run out of space and run all calls to Perl? (This might not even be the precise question to ask.)

Comment: *"I have some arcane perl code that computes a distance between two strings."* Why not let R do the string distance computation? Can you share some details on what string distance metric you're using? There is also [`stringdist`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/stringdist.pdf) that offers "various string distances based on edits
(Damerau-Levenshtein, Hamming, Levenshtein, optimal sting alignment), qgrams (qgram, cosine, jaccard distance) or heuristic metrics (Jaro, Jaro-Winkler)."

Comment: Seconded. Also, when it matters, Rcpp has often come to the rescue for text processing.  Examples are on the Rcpp Gallery and in various CRAN packages.

Comment: Otherwise, trivially:  _"I can't figure out how to make R simply send all commands to the same shell"._  That is not how `system()` works.  You need to rework the logic.  Maybe you can spill out the loop parameters and write a new Perl (meta-script) that loops and calls the other code.  In short, you have a bazillion `system()` calls with so ... just don't call `system()` a bazillion times.

Comment: Rewriting the perl script in R *is* the straightforward thing to do. Unfortunately, it's a 1000-line monster and I'm not much of a perl ninja. So I can't do it. That's why I was trying to cheat my way out of this.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on the suggestion of [Dirk Eddelbuettel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel) I wrote all the possible argument pairs into a bazillion-line txt file and used a bash script to go through the txt file and run the perl script on each line. Since the arguments are strings this is a possible solution here. In the end it does work.

Comment: I wonder if it would be too complicated to wrap the 'maintop' of the Perl script in just one extra layer and read in the 'bazillion-line' txt file